# IllegalStateException: The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-1

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, reactive

I am trying to use quarkus reactive api to fetch data from another hibernate reactive project.
I am getting this error whenever i try to get data from my hibernate project. I've figured that the error occurs in methods where i've called another method as well.[the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctgzt.png)

code for quarkus api

```
@GET
@Path("/getEquipCls")
public Uni<List<Tuple>> getMethod() {
    return reactiveMethod();                
}
```

code for service class of hibernate reactive method

```
@Override
public Uni<List<Tuple>> reactiveMethod(params) {
    Long variable = methodForVariable.await().indefinitely();
    return reactiveMethod(variable);
}
```

I've tried @Blocking & @NonBlocking annotations but none of them worked.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a bit of misunderstanding, Reactive is not the same as Mutiny.
Returning Type `Uni<>` or `Multi<>` from your method is Mutiny. Which could be Reactive, but it's not always the case depending on what dependencies you added.

That said, I've seen that you call `await().indefinitely();` which wait for result and then give the correct non Uni type.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Mutiny expert so i'll try to help as much as i can.

Maybe you should try with this :

```
return methodForVariable.onItem()
    .transform(variable -> reactiveMethod(variable))
```

instead of this :

```
Long variable = methodForVariable.await().indefinitely();
return reactiveMethod(variable);
```

I think your blocking problem comes from here, where you try to block thread to wait for async processing, and then call an async method with previously fetched value.
The way i suggested always keep processing async, so it should do the trick.

For more, be sure to check [Mutiny's documentation](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides)